# Generate c call graph without library calls

Tags: c, call-graph

I want to easily create a c call hierarchy, without listing the calls to library functions, since those usually clutter the output. I tried cflow and vim's cctree, but failed with both. Does anyone know a similar tool that can do this?

Comment: mmm... You could exclude symbols with ^ sign

Comment: I tried this, but the calls stay in there. I tried: `cflow -i -s source.c`